# Convert Hex-CString with invalid characters to long?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, hex, c-strings

I use the function strtol to convert a Hex-CString into a long.

```
CString data = "A";
TCHAR *end = NULL;
long value = strtol(data, &end, 16);
```

At first glance, everything looks very good. "A" becomes 10, "AC" becomes 172 and "ACC" becomes 2764. Everything you would expect.
Unfortunately strtol also converts the value if only the beginning of the CString is a valid hex value.

"ACCUMULATOR" also becomes 2764!

How can I prevent that?

Or how can I check if my CString is a valid hex number?

Comment: Library calls tend to believe you when you tell them its a string they can convert.

Comment: just apply the inverse operation to the result and check if it is the same as the original

Comment: You may find that reading the reference material helps you in future:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if `*end == '\0'`. This means the whole string was parsed, up to the null-terminator.

In the case of `ACCUMULATOR`, it will point to the character `U`. Thus, you can find out up to wich point the string was valid

Comment: Also check if `data` is not empty beforehand, as for an empty string `strotol` would return `0` and `*end` would be `'\0'` as well.